# How to default export from a directory in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following dir structure

```
- common
|
|--- Component1
|   |
|   |--- index.js
|   |--- Component1.tsx
|   |--- Component1.scss
|
|--- Component2.tsx
|
```

In Component1's `index.js` and Compoennt1.tsx I export the default

Component1/index.js

```js
export { default as Component1 } from './Component1'
```

Component1/Component1.tsx

```js
const Component1 = () => { code... }

export default Component1
```

and in `Component2.tsx` I want to import `Component1.tsx` through default import. However it complains 'no default export in /Component1/index'.
I think the directory `/Compoennt1` is exporting `Component1.tsx` as default, but it's not working

Component2.tsx

```js
// doesn't work
import Component1 from './Component1'

// both works
import { Component1 } from './Component1' or
import Component1 from './Component1/Component1'
```

Can someone explain why I can't default export/import when it's through a folder or is this how imports/exports work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, it's a named export (named `Component1`), not a default export:

```
export { default as Component1 } from './Component1'
```

which is why importing it via named imports works here:

```
import { Component1 } from './Component1'
```

If you want to make it the default export for the `Component1/index.js`, you need

```
export { default as default} from './Component1'
```

Personally, I like to be consistent when writing code - it's nice not to have to try to recall, for *every single module*, "Did this module export a default or something named?" In a given project, you may find it easier to use default exports everywhere, or named exports everywhere, but not mix them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So in my case which imports do you think the best for consistency? I'm not too sure if writing default as default would be easier to understand to others. Guess maybe import { Component1 } from './Component1' is the way to go?

Comment: It's up to you. To be opinion-based, I prefer named exports all the time, because occasionally you'll run into a situation where you want a module to export more than one thing (and so a default export wouldn't work well) - while also keeping in mind that 95% of the time, a module should do only one thing, so there should be only one such named export most of the time. Named exports also help keep identifier naming consistent.

Comment: "but not mix them." The problem with that statement is that there can only be one default export per file, and files are rarely that simple. So you almost certainly will require named exports alongside those defaults, and now you're mixing them. Where if you start with named exports you can use named exports forever without ever having to use a default.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, that's why I prefer always using named exports, because eventually there'll be a point where you find a module that needs to export more than one thing. Technically you can still use a default export, and export an object with multiple properties, but having the consumer deal with that is ugly.